# Hi, I'm trying do an https post request that requires authentication and multiple parameters, how would I do this?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, oauth, parameters

I'm pretty new to both Node.js and this particular API and I'm struggling to figure out how to do this correctly. I've been reading through the [request](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication) documentation, and I've made some progress, but I'm still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the link that you posted.

You didn't say what kind of authentication you need but it's explained to do basic and bearer authentication like this:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth(null, null, true, 'bearerToken');
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': 'bearerToken'
  }
});
```

For POST use `.post()` instead of `.get()`.

You also didn't say if you need to pass the data as JSON or application/x-www-form-urlencoded but both are explained in the documentation, for example:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
```

See the documentation for more details. Everything that you ask about is explained there:

- https://github.com/request/request